# How to use unspecified arguments with clap

Tags: rust, clap

I want to create a CLI application using the clap library. The problem I have is that I want to use my application like this :

```
./my_app file.txt read2.txt -d
```

The objective is that I can recover in my program in the form of `Vec` with `file.txt read2.txt` values.

my code :

```rs
use clap::{App, load_yaml};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum EFlag {
    Debug,
    None,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Flag {
    debug: EFlag,
}

impl Flag {
    pub fn new() -> Flag {
        Flag {
            debug: EFlag::None,
        }
    }

    pub fn fill_flag(&mut self) {
        let yaml = load_yaml!("cli.yaml");
        let matches = App::from(yaml).get_matches();

        match matches.is_present("debug") {
            true => self.debug = EFlag::Debug,
            _ => self.debug = EFlag::None,
        }
        // HERE I WANT TO RECEIVE file.txt file2.txt
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut flag = Flag::new();
    flag.fill_flag();
}
```

I use the beta version of clap to create a yaml file to manage the flags.

the yaml file :

```yaml
name: bs-script
version: "1.0.0"
author: Clement B. <clement.bolin@epitech.eu>
about: Write perform, secure and easy script with an Rust script interpretor
args:
  - debug:
      short: d
      long: debug
      about: display debug information
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an argument accept zero-to-many values, you just need to specify `multiple: true`.

```yaml
- files:
    multiple: true
```

Then to obtain the files you'd use [`values_of()`](https://docs.rs/clap-v3/3.0.0-beta.1/clap_v3/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.values_of) along with a [`collect::<Vec<&str>>()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```rust
if let Some(files) = matches.values_of("files") {
    let files = files.collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", files);
}

// Prints nothing                     for `cargo run -- -d`
// Prints `["file.txt"]`              for `cargo run -- file.txt -d`
// Prints `["file.txt", "read2.txt"]` for `cargo run -- file.txt read2.txt -d`
```

---

Here's the complete `cli.yaml`:

```yaml
name: bs-script
version: "1.0.0"
author: Clement B. <clement.bolin@epitech.eu>
about: Write perform, secure and easy script with an Rust script interpretor
args:
  - files:
      multiple: true
      about: Files
  - debug:
      short: d
      long: debug
      about: display debug information
```